# WiFi and Ethernet behavior

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have a wireless router 150M Wireless Lite N Router Model No. TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND. I'm using Linux Mint. Normally, when I'm connected to the local network using eth0 I can ping other machines by issuing `ping name`. When I'm connected through WiFi I have to issue `ping name.domain.com`. The machine is only visible in the intranet.

How can I achieve the same behavior with WiFi?

Additionally I'm unable to connect to some external sites through WiFi but through Ethernet everything is fine. I guess that it is related to some port forwarding, but I'm not sure. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint

Comment: Check the official FAQ: http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/faq/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it in this way.

I've installed the software included in the mini CD on a Windows PC. Configured the wireless network, upgraded the firmware, password, etc.

Then I've simply connected the tl-wr740n to my Linux PC and `networkmanager` worked fine.
(It worked with `wicd` too).
I can access internet with no limitations, no port forwarding problems.